# Reasons to keep stuff on separate partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Often partition are used to separate stuff on hard disks. But if the physical hard disk is the same, what's the reason to separate my os and folders into different partitions? Also, there is difference in this habit if I'm using hdd /ssd?

Comment: Partition corruption, malware targetting a single partition, OS restore won't impact files on another partition (in most cases), to suggest a few..

Comment: It is a matter of opinion really - I don't see how you can get a decent answer.  Speed in the olden days (put some data in faster part of disk), ease of backup/restore but it is all opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons:

1. Separate OS data from personal data.
2. If the OS is corrupted, data on the other partition(s) won't be affected.
3. Install different OSes on the same computer.
4. Possibility to create image of one partition to another